# Torch, "size mismatch" in StochasticGradient function training

Tags: lua, neural-network, deep-learning, torch

I'm implementing a deep neural network in Torch7 with a dataset made of two torch.Tensor() objects.
The first is made of 12 elements (completeTable), the other one is made of 1 element (presentValue).
Each dataset row is an array of these two tensors:

```
dataset[p] = {torch.Tensor(completeTable[p]), torch.Tensor(presentValue)};
```

Everything works for the neural network training and testing.
But now I want to switch and use only half of the 12 elements of completeTable, that are only 6 elements (firstChromRegionProfile).

```
dataset_firstChromRegion[p] = {torch.Tensor(firstChromRegionProfile), torch.Tensor(presentValue)};
```

If I run the same neural network architecture with this new dataset, it does not work. **It says that the trainer:train(dataset_firstChromRegion) function cannot work because of "size mismatch".**

Here's my neural network function:

```
-- Neural network application
function neuralNetworkApplication(input_number, output_number, datasetTrain, datasetTest, dropOutFlag, hiddenUnits, hiddenLayers)

      require "nn"
    -- act_function = nn.Sigmoid();
    act_function = nn.Tanh();

    print('input_number '.. input_number);
    print('output_number '.. output_number);

      -- NEURAL NETWORK CREATION - <START>

      perceptron=nn.Sequential();  -- make a multi-layer perceptron
      perceptron:add(nn.Linear(input_number, hiddenUnits));
      perceptron:add(act_function);
      if dropOutFlag==TRUE then perceptron:add(nn.Dropout()) end  -- DROPOUT

        -- we add w layers DEEP LEARNING
      for w=0, hiddenLayers do
          perceptron:add(nn.Linear(hiddenUnits,hiddenUnits)) -- DEEP LEARNING layer
          perceptron:add(act_function); -- DEEP LEARNING 
          if dropOutFlag==TRUE then 
        perceptron:add(nn.Dropout())  -- DROPOUT
          end
      end

    print('\n#datasetTrain '.. #datasetTrain);
    print('#datasetTrain[1] '.. #datasetTrain[1]);
    print('(#datasetTrain[1][1])[1] '..(#datasetTrain[1][1])[1]);
    print('\n#datasetTest '.. #datasetTest);
    print('#datasetTest[1] '.. #datasetTest[1]);
    print('(#datasetTest[1][1])[1] '..(#datasetTest[1][1])[1]);

      perceptron:add(nn.Linear(hiddenUnits, output_number));
      perceptron:add(act_function);

      criterion = nn.MSECriterion();  -- MSE: Mean Square Error
      trainer = nn.StochasticGradient(perceptron, criterion)
      trainer.learningRate = LEARNING_RATE_CONST;
      trainer:train(datasetTrain);

      idp=3;
      predValueVector={}
      for i=1,(#datasetTest) do
        pred=perceptron:forward(datasetTest[i][1]);  -- get the prediction of the perceptron 
        predValueVector[i]=pred[1];     
      end

      -- NEURAL NETWORK CREATION - <END>

    return predValueVector;

end
```

Here's the error log:

```
input_number 6  
output_number 1 

#datasetTrain 13416 
#datasetTrain[1] 2  
(#datasetTrain[1][1])[1] 6  

#datasetTest 3354   
#datasetTest[1] 2   
(#datasetTest[1][1])[1] 6   
# StochasticGradient: training  
/mnt/work1/software/torch/7/bin/luajit: /mnt/work1/software/torch/7/share/lua/5.1/nn/Linear.lua:71: size mismatch
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'addmv'
    /mnt/work1/software/torch/7/share/lua/5.1/nn/Linear.lua:71: in function 'updateGradInput'
    /mnt/work1/software/torch/7/share/lua/5.1/nn/Sequential.lua:36: in function 'updateGradInput'
    ...software/torch/7/share/lua/5.1/nn/StochasticGradient.lua:37: in function 'train'
    siamese_neural_network.lua:278: in function 'neuralNetworkApplication'
    siamese_neural_network.lua:223: in function 'kfold_cross_validation_separate'
    siamese_neural_network.lua:753: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    ...1/software/torch/7/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:131: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x004057d0
```

Comment: @smhx Hey, you know a lot about Torch and Lua, could you help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All of your activation layers share the same `nn.Tanh()` object. That is the problem. Try something like this instead:

```
act_function = nn.Tanh
perceptron:add( act_function() )
```

Why?

To perform a backward propagation step, we have to compute a gradient of the layer w.r.t. its input. In our case:

> tanh'(input) = 1 - **tanh(input)**^2

One can notice that **tanh(input)** = **output** of the layer's forward step. You can store this output inside the layer and use it during backward pass to speed up training. This is exactly what happens inside `nn` library:

```
// torch/nn/generic/Tanh.c/Tanh_updateGradInput:

for(i = 0; i < THTensor_(nElement)(gradInput); i++)
    {
        real z = ptr_output[i];
        ptr_gradInput[i] = ptr_gradOutput[i] * (1. - z*z);
    }
```

Output sizes of your activation layers don't match, so error occurs. Even if they did, it would lead to wrong result.

Sorry about my English.

Answer (score 0):

I was surprisingly able to fix my problem, by eliminating the line:

```
act_function = nn.Tanh();
```

and consequently by replacing any occurrences of `act_function` with `nn.Tanh()`

I do not why, but know everything works...
So the lesson is: never assign an activation function to a variable (!?).